# Using Star size and temperature to determine habitable zone JS

Tags: javascript, math, astronomy, orbital-mechanics

So I went online to find out how you can calculate the temperature of a planetary body based on the size and temperature of its star, and the body's distance from its star. That brought about this solution:

```
function calcBodyTempSolar(starTemp, starRadius, bodySemiMajorAxis) { //MAGIC math. Determines approx. body temp based on the body's distance from it's star.
return starTemp*Math.sqrt(starRadius/(2 * bodySemiMajorAxis)) * Math.pow(.7, 1/4)}
```

Next I thought "If I can know how hot a planet will be at a given distance, can I reverse that to determine the "Habitable Zone"?"

I reversed the equation above, but I'm getting the wrong numbers.

```
(Math.pow(starTemp/(254.58 * Math.pow(0.7, 1/4)), 2) * (starRadius/2))/AU
```

Running the above equation gives me the wrong number. I have input the proper temperature of earth* but it isn't giving me the right answer. (should be 1, is 1.428...)

*if earth had no atmosphere.

The source of the equations above, is here: [https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~strauss/FRS113/writeup3/](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Estrauss/FRS113/writeup3/)

I'm thinking that I simply reversed the first equation wrong. But I'm not sure. Any math people here to weigh in?

Comment: not my field of expertise but where is albedo of planet? Where is atmosphere? If you account only incoming energy I would think star size is irrelevant what is important is: energy emitted (might be a function of start size, star temp and type), energy absorbed (function of planet distance size orientation/rotation, albedo, atmospheric effects, shadows by other objects like moons rings dust)  energy emmited back (planet surface area, other factors) and do not forget that some parametters differs with wavelength...

Comment: Good point. This calculation assumes that the albedo is .3. That's what the 0.7 is all about. Atmosphere will play a large factor in the temperature of the planet, but I haven't figured that out yet. If you know of a good source for atmospheric calculations/greenhouse effect, I'd appreciate it. I'm thinking of just adding a number that is relative to the increase that earth experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the equation in the source this should be the planet temperature based on star, size and distance. (That part you got right). The reverse is just as simple

```js
function calcPlanetTemp(starTemp, starRadius, distance, absorbtion) {
  absorbtion = absorbtion || 0.7
  return starTemp * Math.sqrt(starRadius / (2 * distance)) * Math.pow(absorbtion, 1 / 4)
}

var AU = 150 * 1e6; // distance to sun = 1 astornomical unit


// for earth and sun:
var planetTemp = calcPlanetTemp(6000, 700000, AU)
console.log("earth temp (celsius): ", planetTemp - 273.15)
console.log("(that's minus the greenhouse effect)")
// 265.1027012854874
/*
function calcStarTemp(planetTemp, starRadius, distance, absorbtion) {
  absorbtion = absorbtion || 0.7
  return planetTemp / (Math.sqrt(starRadius / (2 * distance)) * Math.pow(absorbtion, 1 / 4))
}
console.log("sun temp: ", calcStarTemp(planetTemp, 700000, AU))
*/

function calcDistance(planetTemp, starTemp, starRadius, absorbtion) {
  absorbtion = absorbtion || 0.7
  return 1 / (Math.pow(planetTemp / starTemp / Math.pow(absorbtion, 1 / 4), 2) * 2 / starRadius)
}
console.log("distance from sun: ", calcDistance(planetTemp, 6000, 700000, 0.7))
```

Comment: Ah. That helps a lot! The question now is how to solve for the distance if I know the temperature.

Comment: Oh man! This is a life saver! I'm not sure why I couldn't figure this one out! Thanks!!